# Flash load images not using XML

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

Ok so I got this demo Flash file which loads images through XML and adds different effects.  Currently it's being used as a banner on a page.  Now I have been asked to keep the effects but to embed to pictures inside Flash (so to get rid of the XML).  I am clueless on how to change this to not read from XML.  Any help would be greatly appreciated because I stopped using Flash back in MX era... :S

```
import caurina.transitions.Tweener;
import caurina.transitions.properties.ColorShortcuts;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

ColorShortcuts.init();

var hover_effect:Boolean;
var auto_play:Boolean;
var auto_play_duration:Number = 3000;
var no_of_rows:uint = 4;
var no_of_columns:uint = 8;

var tween_duration:Number = 0.7;
var tween_delay:Number = 0.03;
var block_scale:Number = 0.1;
var flashmo_margin:Number = 10;
var offstage_position:Number = 300;

var i:Number;
var j:Number;
var new_x:Number;
var new_y:Number;
var pic:Number = 0;
var previous_no:Number = 0;
var current_no:Number = 0;
var total:Number;

var timer:Timer;
var flashmo_xml:XML;
var flashmo_photo_list = new Array();
var mc:MovieClip;
var photo_group:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
var circle_group:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
var photo_array:Array;
var photo_group_array:Array;
var size_width:uint;
var size_height:uint;
var photo_width:uint;
var photo_height:uint;

stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;

photo_group.mask = flashmo_photo_area;
photo_group_array = [];
photo_button.alpha = 0;
flashmo_cover.visible = false;
flashmo_bar.flashmo_next.visible = false;
flashmo_bar.flashmo_previous.visible = false;
flashmo_bar.flashmo_play.visible = false; 
flashmo_bar.flashmo_pause.visible = false;

flashmo_bar.addChild(circle_group);
this.addChildAt(photo_group, 1);
this.addChild(photo_button);
this.addChild(flashmo_bar);

function load_gallery(xml_file:String):void
{

create_photo_rotator();
}

//remove argument since it is no longer being passed the Event
function create_photo_rotator():void
{   
    //manually set a bunch of properties that the XML normally would have
    hover_effect=true;
    auto_play=true; 
    auto_play_duration=2.4;
    //grid_row=3;
    //grid_column=9; 
    tween_duration=0.7; 
    tween_delay=0.03;

    //manually build array of photo objects
    //notice that "Photo1" is the filename, same as the photo Class name we set above
    //add as many of this code block as there are embedded photos
    flashmo_photo_list.push({
        filename: "slide1",
        flow: "in",
        direction: "right",
        rotation: ""
    });

    flashmo_photo_list.push({
        filename: "slide2",
        flow: "in",
        direction: "left",
        rotation: ""
    });

    flashmo_photo_list.push({
        filename: "slide3",
        flow: "in",
        direction: "down",
        rotation: "-180"
    });

    flashmo_photo_list.push({
        filename: "slide4",
        flow: "in",
        direction: "up",
        rotation: ""
    });

    total = flashmo_photo_list.length;

    load_photo();

}

function load_photo():void
{
    //manually call on_photo_loaded and pass it current photo index
    on_photo_loaded(pic);
    pic++;

    load_circle();

}

function load_circle():void
{
    var fm_circle:MovieClip = new flashmo_circle();
    fm_circle.x = 5 + ( fm_circle.width + 4 ) * ( pic - 1 ) + fm_circle.width * 0.5;
    fm_circle.y = ( flashmo_bar.bar.height - fm_circle.height ) * 0.5;  
    fm_circle.name = "flashmo_circle_" + circle_group.numChildren;
    fm_circle.visible = false;
    circle_group.addChild( fm_circle );

    if( circle_group.numChildren == 1 )
    {       
        Tweener.addTween( fm_circle , { _color_redOffset: 255, _color_greenOffset: 255, 
                     _color_blueOffset: 255, time: tween_duration, transition: "easeIn" } );
    }
}

function on_photo_progress(e:ProgressEvent):void
{
    var percent:Number = Math.round(e.bytesLoaded / e.bytesTotal * 100);

}

//change argument to expect photo index instead of Event
function on_photo_loaded(photoIndex:int):void
{   
    mc = MovieClip( circle_group.getChildAt( pic - 1 ) );
    mc.visible = true;

    //create Bitmap from embedded image's BitmapData
    var photoBitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(flashmo_photo_list[photoIndex].filename);

    if( pic == 1 )
    {
        //adjust values on newly created Bitmap
        photo_width = photoBitmap.width;
        photo_height = photoBitmap.height;

        adjust_size();
    }
    else if( pic > 1 )
    {
        enable_circle( mc );

        if( pic == 2 )
        {
            flashmo_bar.flashmo_previous.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, pic_previous );
            flashmo_bar.flashmo_next.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, pic_next );            
            flashmo_bar.flashmo_play.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, pic_play );
            flashmo_bar.flashmo_pause.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, pic_pause );
            flashmo_bar.flashmo_previous.visible = flashmo_bar.flashmo_next.visible = true;

            timer = new Timer(auto_play_duration);
            timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, auto_play_timer);

            if( auto_play )
            {
                flashmo_bar.flashmo_play.visible = false;
                flashmo_bar.flashmo_pause.visible = true;

                timer.start();
            }
            else
            {
                flashmo_bar.flashmo_play.visible = true;
                flashmo_bar.flashmo_pause.visible = false;
            }           
        }
    }

    if( pic < total )
    {
        load_photo();
    }

    //pass the Bitmap to create_effect (which is already expecting a Bitmap)
    create_effect( photoBitmap );

}

function adjust_size():void
{
    flashmo_photo_area.width = photo_button.width = flashmo_bar.bar.width = photo_width;
    flashmo_photo_area.height = photo_button.height = photo_height;

    flashmo_bar.flashmo_next.x = 
            flashmo_bar.bar.width - flashmo_bar.flashmo_next.width - flashmo_margin * 0.5;

    flashmo_bar.flashmo_previous.x = flashmo_bar.flashmo_next.x - flashmo_bar.flashmo_next.width;

    flashmo_bar.flashmo_play.x = flashmo_bar.flashmo_pause.x = 
            flashmo_bar.flashmo_previous.x - flashmo_bar.flashmo_previous.width;

    flashmo_bar.y = photo_height;
    photo_group.x = flashmo_photo_area.x;
    photo_group.y = flashmo_photo_area.y;
    photo_group.mask = flashmo_photo_area;
}

function create_effect( bitmap:Bitmap ):void
{   
    var flashmo_pic_mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();

    size_width  = Math.ceil( photo_width / no_of_columns );
    size_height = Math.ceil( photo_height / no_of_rows );
    photo_array = [];

    if( photo_group.x == flashmo_photo_area.x )
    {
        photo_group.x += size_width * 0.5;
        photo_group.y += size_height * 0.5;
    }

    for( j = 0; j < no_of_rows; j++ )
    {
        for( i = 0; i < no_of_columns; i++ )
        {                                                       
            var temp_bitmap_data:BitmapData = new BitmapData ( size_width, size_height, true, 0xFFFFFF );
            var source_rect:Rectangle = new Rectangle ( i * size_width, j * size_height, 
                                                       size_width, size_height );

            temp_bitmap_data.copyPixels ( bitmap.bitmapData, source_rect, new Point );

            var temp_bitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap ( temp_bitmap_data );
            var temp_sprite:Sprite = new Sprite;

            temp_bitmap.smoothing = true;
            temp_bitmap.x = - temp_bitmap.width * 0.5;
            temp_bitmap.y = - temp_bitmap.height * 0.5;

            temp_sprite.addChild ( temp_bitmap );
            temp_sprite.x = i * size_width;

            if( photo_group.numChildren > 0 )
                temp_sprite.y = photo_height;
            else
                temp_sprite.y = j * size_height;

            photo_array.push ( temp_sprite );
            flashmo_pic_mc.addChild( temp_sprite );
        }
    }

    flashmo_pic_mc.name = "flashmo_pic_" + photo_group.numChildren;
    photo_group_array.push( photo_array );
    photo_group.addChild ( flashmo_pic_mc );
}

function auto_play_timer(te:TimerEvent):void
{
    current_no++;
    change_photo();
}

function change_photo():void
{
    if( current_no >= photo_group.numChildren ) 
        current_no = 0;
    if( current_no < 0 )
        current_no = photo_group.numChildren - 1;

    var flashmo_direction:String = flashmo_photo_list[current_no].direction;
    var flashmo_rotation_str:String = flashmo_photo_list[current_no].rotation;
    var flashmo_rotation:Number = 0;

    if( flashmo_direction == "" )
        flashmo_direction = "center";

    if( flashmo_rotation_str != "" )
        flashmo_rotation = parseInt( flashmo_rotation_str );

    if( flashmo_photo_list[current_no].flow == "in" )
        transition_in( current_no, flashmo_direction, flashmo_rotation );
    else
        transition_out( previous_no, flashmo_direction, flashmo_rotation );

    disable_buttons();
}

function transition_in( pic_index:uint, from_direction:String, flashmo_rotation:Number ):void
{
    photo_group.addChild( photo_group.getChildByName( "flashmo_pic_" + pic_index ) );
    photo_array = photo_group_array[ pic_index ];

    var row_no:uint;
    var column_no:uint;

    for (i = 0; i < photo_array.length ; i++)
    {       
        if( flashmo_rotation != 0 )
            photo_array[i].rotation = flashmo_rotation;

        photo_array[i].scaleX = photo_array[i].scaleY = block_scale;
        photo_array[i].alpha = 0;

        if( from_direction == "left" )
        {
            photo_array[i].x = - size_width;            
            photo_array[i].y = Math.floor( i / no_of_columns ) * size_height;
        }
        else if( from_direction == "right" )
        {
            photo_array[i].x = photo_width;
            photo_array[i].y = Math.floor( i / no_of_columns ) * size_height;
        }
        else if( from_direction == "up" )
        {
            photo_array[i].x =  ( i % no_of_columns ) * size_width ;
            photo_array[i].y =  - size_height;
        }
        else if( from_direction == "down" )
        {
            photo_array[i].x = ( i % no_of_columns ) * size_width;
            photo_array[i].y = photo_height;
            photo_array[i].scaleX = photo_array[i].scaleY = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            photo_array[i].x = ( i % no_of_columns ) * size_width;
            photo_array[i].y = Math.floor( i / no_of_columns ) * size_height;           
        }
    }

    for ( i = 0; i < photo_array.length ; i++ )
    {       
        if( from_direction == "left" )
        {
            j = photo_array.length - i - 1;
            j = ( j % no_of_rows ) * no_of_columns + Math.floor( j / no_of_rows );

            new_x = ( j % no_of_columns ) * size_width;
            new_y = photo_array[j].y;
        }
        else if( from_direction == "right" )
        {
            j = ( i % no_of_rows ) * no_of_columns + Math.floor( i / no_of_rows );
            new_x = ( j % no_of_columns ) * size_width;
            new_y = photo_array[j].y;
        }
        else if( from_direction == "up" )
        {
            j = photo_array.length - i - 1;
            new_x = photo_array[j].x;
            new_y = Math.floor( j / no_of_columns ) * size_height;
        }
        else if( from_direction == "down" )
        {
            j = i;
            new_x = photo_array[j].x;
            new_y = Math.floor( j / no_of_columns ) * size_height;
        }
        else
        {
            j = i;
            new_x = photo_array[j].x;
            new_y = photo_array[j].y;
        }

        Tweener.addTween ( photo_array[j], { x: new_x, y: new_y,
            alpha: 1, scaleX: 1, scaleY: 1, rotation: 0,
            delay: tween_delay * i, time: tween_duration, transition: "easeOutQuart",
            onComplete: transition_complete, onCompleteParams:[i, true] }   );
    }
}

function transition_complete( no:Number, transition_in:Boolean ):void
{
    if( no == photo_array.length - 1 )
    {       
        if( transition_in )
        {
            photo_array = photo_group_array[ previous_no ];

            var sprite_index:Number = 0;

            for ( j = 0; j < no_of_rows; j++ )
            {
                for ( i = 0; i < no_of_columns; i++ )
                {   
                    photo_array[ sprite_index ].x = -1000;
                    photo_array[ sprite_index ].y = -1000;          
                    sprite_index++;         
                }
            }
        }

        enable_buttons();
    }
}

function transition_out( pic_index:uint, to_direction:String, flashmo_rotation:Number ):void
{
    photo_group.addChild( photo_group.getChildByName( "flashmo_pic_" + current_no ) );
    photo_group.addChild( photo_group.getChildByName( "flashmo_pic_" + pic_index ) );
    photo_array = photo_group_array[ pic_index ];

    var flashmo_effect:String = "easeInQuart";

    for ( i = 0; i < photo_array.length ; i++)
    {       
        if( to_direction == "left" )
        {
            j = ( i % no_of_rows ) * no_of_columns + Math.floor( i / no_of_rows );
            new_x = - offstage_position;
            new_y = photo_array[j].y;
        }
        else if( to_direction == "right" )
        {
            j = photo_array.length - i - 1;
            j = ( j % no_of_rows ) * no_of_columns + Math.floor( j / no_of_rows );
            new_x = photo_width + offstage_position;
            new_y = photo_array[j].y;
        }       
        else if( to_direction == "up" )
        {
            j = i;
            new_x = photo_array[j].x;
            new_y = - offstage_position;
        }
        else if( to_direction == "down" )
        {
            j = photo_array.length - i - 1;
            new_x = photo_array[j].x;
            new_y = photo_height + offstage_position;           
        }
        else
        {
            j = i;
            new_x = photo_array[j].x;
            new_y = photo_array[j].y;
            flashmo_effect = "easeInOutQuart";
        }

        Tweener.addTween ( photo_array[j], { x: new_x, y: new_y,
            scaleX: block_scale, scaleY: block_scale, alpha: 0, rotation: flashmo_rotation, 
            delay: tween_delay * i, time: tween_duration, transition: flashmo_effect,
            onComplete: transition_complete, onCompleteParams:[i, false] } );
    }

    to_normal_position( current_no );
}

function to_normal_position( pic_index:uint ):void
{
    photo_array = photo_group_array[ pic_index ];

    var sprite_index:Number = 0;

    for ( j = 0; j < no_of_rows; j++ )
    {
        for ( i = 0; i < no_of_columns; i++ )
        {   
            photo_array[ sprite_index ].rotation = 0;
            photo_array[ sprite_index ].alpha = 
            photo_array[ sprite_index ].scaleX = 
            photo_array[ sprite_index ].scaleY = 1;         
            photo_array[ sprite_index ].x = i * size_width;
            photo_array[ sprite_index ].y = j * size_height;            
            sprite_index++;         
        }
    }
}


function pic_over(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    Tweener.addTween( photo_button, { alpha: 0.15, time: tween_duration, transition: "easeIn" } );
}

function pic_out(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    Tweener.addTween( photo_button, { alpha: 0, time: tween_duration, transition: "easeOut" } );
}

function pic_previous(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    current_no--;
    change_photo();
}

function pic_next( e:MouseEvent ):void
{
    current_no++;
    change_photo();
}

function pic_play(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    flashmo_bar.flashmo_pause.visible = true;
    flashmo_bar.flashmo_play.visible = false;
    auto_play = true;

    if( circle_group.alpha == 1 )
        timer.start();
}

function pic_pause(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    flashmo_bar.flashmo_pause.visible = false;
    flashmo_bar.flashmo_play.visible = true;
    auto_play = false;
    timer.reset();
}

function circle_out( me:MouseEvent ):void
{
    mc = MovieClip( me.target );
    Tweener.addTween( mc, { _color_redOffset: 0, _color_greenOffset: 0, 
                     _color_blueOffset: 0, time: tween_duration, transition: "easeIn" } );
}

function circle_over( me:MouseEvent ):void
{
    mc = MovieClip( me.target );
    Tweener.addTween( mc, { _color_redOffset: 255, _color_greenOffset: 255, 
                     _color_blueOffset: 255, time: tween_duration, transition: "easeIn" } );
}

function circle_click( me:MouseEvent ):void
{
    mc = MovieClip( me.target );
    current_no = parseInt( mc.name.slice( 15,17 ) );
    change_photo();
}

function enable_buttons():void
{
    if( auto_play )
        timer.start();
    else
        timer.reset();

    photo_button.visible = true;
    flashmo_bar.flashmo_previous.mouseEnabled = true;
    flashmo_bar.flashmo_next.mouseEnabled = true;

    flashmo_bar.flashmo_previous.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, pic_previous );
    flashmo_bar.flashmo_next.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, pic_next );
    circle_group.alpha = 1;

    for( i = 0; i < circle_group.numChildren; i++ )
    {
        if( i == current_no )
            continue;

        mc = MovieClip( circle_group.getChildAt( i ) );
        enable_circle( mc );
    }

    previous_no = current_no;
}

function disable_buttons():void
{
    if( auto_play )
        timer.reset();

    photo_button.visible = false;
    flashmo_bar.flashmo_previous.mouseEnabled = false;
    flashmo_bar.flashmo_next.mouseEnabled = false;

    flashmo_bar.flashmo_previous.removeEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, pic_previous );
    flashmo_bar.flashmo_next.removeEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, pic_next );
    circle_group.alpha = 0.5;

    for( i = 0; i < circle_group.numChildren; i++ )
    {
        mc = MovieClip( circle_group.getChildAt( i ) );
        disable_circle( mc );
        Tweener.addTween( mc, { _color_redOffset: 0, _color_greenOffset: 0, 
                     _color_blueOffset: 0, time: tween_duration, transition: "easeIn" } );
    }

    mc = MovieClip( circle_group.getChildAt( current_no ) );
    Tweener.addTween( mc , { _color_greenOffset: 255, _color_redOffset: 255,
                     _color_blueOffset: 255, time: tween_duration, transition: "easeIn" } );
}

function enable_circle( mc:MovieClip ):void
{
    mc.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, circle_click );
    mc.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, circle_out );
    mc.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, circle_over );
    mc.buttonMode = true;
}

function disable_circle( mc:MovieClip ):void
{
    mc.removeEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, circle_click );   
    mc.removeEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, circle_out );
    mc.removeEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, circle_over );
    mc.buttonMode = false;
}


Object(root).grid_slider.logo.cotton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,fl_ClickToGoToWebPage);
function fl_ClickToGoToWebPage(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.google.com"), "_self");
}
```

updated code with new error:

```
TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
at original_fla::GridSliderClick_1/create_photo_rotator()
at original_fla::GridSliderClick_1/load_gallery()
at original_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()
```

Comment: Could you clarify - are you looking to not only get rid of the external XML but also get rid of the external images, meaning the images will be embedded in the swf?

Comment: yes exactly instead of loading from xml to load from embedded images but to keep the effects, from what I understand this loads the images in XML into an array, so then it uses that array for effects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things you'll have to do to convert this to not using XML and external images. I'll walk you through it as best I can, but I don't have a lot of info based on the code you provided (for instance, I don't see how this code actually initializes, since it looks like `loadGallery()` is being called by something not posted).

The first thing you'll have to do is embed all of the external images. To do this, you need to import the images into the Flash Library using File > Import > Import to Library...

Once you import all of the images into the Library, your Library should now have a Bitmap and a Symbol for each image. Disregard or delete the Symbols - you won't need them. Right click on each Bitmap, and open up the Properties. Here, name the Bitmap (eg. `Photo1`) in the top dialogue box, and then click the button "Export for ActionScript" down in the "Linkage" area. The "Class" dialogue should automatically populate with Bitmap name (eg. `Photo1`), and the "Base class" dialogue should be `flash.display.BitmapData`.

The images will now be embedded into the swf - what you've done is turn each image into a `BitmapData` class accessible by ActionScript. Now you need to make changes to the code to use these embedded images instead of external ones.

One of the challenges with converting this code is that the code relies on the XML heavily.

It looks to me like the code initializes by something calling the method `load_gallery()`. However, I don't know what is calling that. So keep that method, but just strip it down:

```
function load_gallery(xml_file:String):void
{
    create_photo_rotator();
}
```

That will bypass loading the XML. Next, you need to heavily modify the `create_photo_rotator()` method:

```
//remove argument since it is no longer being passed the Event
function create_photo_rotator():void
{
    //manually set a bunch of properties that the XML normally would have
    hover_effect = <set true or false>;
    auto_play = <set true or false>;
    auto_play_duration = <set number>;
    no_of_rows =  <set number>;
    no_of_columns =  <set number>;
    tween_duration = <set number>;
    tween_delay = <set number>;

    //manually build array of photo objects
    //notice that "Photo1" is the filename, same as the photo Class name we set above
    //add as many of this code block as there are embedded photos
    //**UPDATE**:store an instance of the BitmapData class instead of the name of the class as a string - notice the key name has changed to "bitmapData" instead of "filename"
    flashmo_photo_list.push({
        bitmapData: new Photo1(),
        flow: "<flow string>",
        direction: "<direction string>",
        rotation: "<rotation string>"
    });

    total = flashmo_photo_list.length;

    load_photo();
}
```

**UPDATED:**
Basically, you have to build out of the array of photos data manually, since you no longer have the XML. Just duplicate the block of code pushing the object data into `flashmo_photo_list` for as many photos as you have. Make sure to set the `bitmapData` for each to a new instance of the Class of the associated Bitmap you embedded earlier, and manually set the other attributes (just go through the XML and copy whatever they are set to there). So, if in your library you have a bitmap called "Photo1", and in Photo1's properties you clicked "Export for ActionScript" and set the "Class" to "Photo1", then the code would be: `bitmapData: new Photo1()`.

Now, alter the `load_photo()` method to remove actually loading the photo:

```
function load_photo():void
{
    //manually call on_photo_loaded and pass it current photo index
    on_photo_loaded(pic);
    pic++;

    load_circle();
}
```

Last, alter `on_photo_loaded()` to use the embedded Bitmaps:

```
//change argument to expect photo index instead of Event
function on_photo_loaded(photoIndex:int):void
{   
    mc = MovieClip( circle_group.getChildAt( pic - 1 ) );
    mc.visible = true;

    //create Bitmap from embedded image's BitmapData
    //**UPDATE**: reference the stored bitmapData instead of filename string
    var photoBitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(flashmo_photo_list[photoIndex].bitmapData);

    if( pic == 1 )
    {
        //adjust values on newly created Bitmap
        photo_width = photoBitmap.width;
        photo_height = photoBitmap.height;

        adjust_size();
    }
    else if( pic > 1 )
    {
        enable_circle( mc );

        if( pic == 2 )
        {
            flashmo_bar.flashmo_previous.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, pic_previous );
            flashmo_bar.flashmo_next.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, pic_next );            
            flashmo_bar.flashmo_play.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, pic_play );
            flashmo_bar.flashmo_pause.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, pic_pause );
            flashmo_bar.flashmo_previous.visible = flashmo_bar.flashmo_next.visible = true;

            timer = new Timer(auto_play_duration);
            timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, auto_play_timer);

            if( auto_play )
            {
                flashmo_bar.flashmo_play.visible = false;
                flashmo_bar.flashmo_pause.visible = true;

                timer.start();
            }
            else
            {
                flashmo_bar.flashmo_play.visible = true;
                flashmo_bar.flashmo_pause.visible = false;
            }           
        }
    }

    if( pic < total )
    {
        load_photo();
    }

    //pass the Bitmap to create_effect (which is already expecting a Bitmap)
    create_effect( photoBitmap );
}
```

The reason you're making a `new Bitmap` is because the photos you embedded earlier are exported as `BitmapData` classes, so you're using that `BitmapData` to create the photo `Bitmap`. **UPDATED:** Make sure you as referencing the "bitmapData" value on the object instead of the previously used "filename" value.

Based on the code you provided, those changes should accomplish what you are asking for. I can't test it myself, however, so you may still need to tweak a couple of things.

Comment: **Disclaimer:** Since the original code you posted is pretty terrible, my advise would be to rewrite the whole thing. But if your back is up against the wall, hopefully the above suggestions will help you out. Just keep in mind that these changes are "hacky" at best, and consider them "emergency only", since they really are not best practice (best practice would probably require a major overhaul of the entire project).

Comment: Ok did everything as should, but now im getting an error with my imports like: import caurina.transitions.Tweener;
all it says is it can't be found?..

Comment: Did this error only start after you made the changes? Did you move the FLA or delete anything? The compiler is throwing an error because it can't find the Tweener class. There should be a folder next to the FLA called "caurina". If you can't find it, then you can download it here: http://code.google.com/p/tweener/downloads/detail?name=tweener_1_33_74_as3.zip

Comment: man i hate to be bugging so much now that made it work but now i get this: TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
 at original_fla::GridSliderClick_1/create_photo_rotator()
 at original_fla::GridSliderClick_1/load_gallery()
 at original_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()

Comment: I don't mind, you're not bugging me - though once you're satisfied with the answer, I'd appreciate if you marked it "Answered" :) As far as your question, it's saying that a variable in the create_photo_rotator method is undefined - hard to know what it is right now. Try turning on debugging - File > Publish Settings > <"Flash" tab> > <"Advanced" section> > Turn on "Permit debugging". Then tell me what the error is next time you run it. You can also try to narrow down the problem var by putting in traces - see what was the last trace outputted before it hits the problem var to find it.

Comment: Of course I mark all answers as accepted if it did the trick or atleast guided me enough to where I was able to figure it out, and technically your answer did work but the error has to do with the code you provided, the reason i say this is because it happens here:     flashmo_photo_list.push({
        filename: "slide1",
        flow: "in",
        direction: "right",
        rotation: "0"
    });
and so the images don't load at all

Comment: Did you try turning on Permit Debugging? I could use some more detailed info. Right now, I see nothing (and confirmed with a temp build myself) that would cause an error in create_photo_rotator(). There is, however, an error I found elsewhere that could cause issues. The code is not correctly referencing the exported BitmapData classes when making the bitmaps. That error should be thrown from the on_photo_loaded method, which is why I'm confused about the error you are getting right now. I have updated my answer to correct that error.

Comment: Thank you i didn't quite figure out why my error was there but it works.  Really appreciate your time in helping me out with this.